# Running codes in Countdown Timer

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I'm creating an app that connect with server(localhost).

In my Activity, I have a countdown timer which will tick for 30 seconds and at the `finish()` I have some code to check if there's any changes in the database on server, and then start the timer again so it'll be a loop in the activity. But the timer seem like running just once. When I'm running in debug mode, the timer get some error at the `finish()`, it said that I'm missing some folder or file that related to the API or the SDK version which is being run in `android:targetSdkVersion="9"`

Please help me with this issue. Here's the activity:

```
public class Account_Activity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //Creating the UI and some methods
   counter = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

       }       

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {
           //Codes for checking the changes in the database on the server
           start(); 
       }
   };
   counter.start();
}
}
```

Do I have to make a thread or not?

Comment: Have you considered using  [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)  and Timer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment vini. As I said, I'm new to android, so I've never had heard of TimerTask, I'll think I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Account_Activity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //Creating the UI and some methods
   counter = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

       }       

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {
           //Codes for checking the changes in the database on the server
           new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000).start(); <------Start Again.
       }
   };
   counter.start();
}
}
```

Comment: I have some more question MAC. As you can see, in the onFinish() method, I have some codes to check the changes in the server, so if I call new CountDownTimer(30000,1000).start(); does it still have the checking codes?

Comment: hey MAC, I tried this but It said that "Cannot instantiate the type CountDownTimer".